# Cannot open include file 'boost/any.hpp' - Invalid argument in VS 2010

Tags: boost, c++11

I have included the path: `$(ProgramFiles)boost\boost_1_42_0` and in source cpp file I have `#include <boost/any.hpp>`. I'm getting the above error which says something about 'Invalid argument'. I think It recognizes the include header file but cannot open it somehow.

Comment: Did you try to install boost elsewhere? In your home directory for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have messed up with INCLUDE environment variable settings. Try specifying the path explicitly as `C:\Program Files` for 64-bit OS or `C:\Program Files(x86)`.

Comment: This worked, but does that mean I can't use $(ProgramFiles) anymore?