# Boost Library cannot get to work in C++, Include directories not working

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

I recently tried to install boost libraries in C++ 14, and I added it's include paths like:

*Solution Explorer > Project Name > Property Pages > VC++ Directories > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\boost"*

I tried to compile after adding this:

```
#include <boost\variant.hpp>
```

In Error List window, I can see `E1696 - cannot open source file "boost\variant.hpp"` and I can't compile like before.

Then I tried with adding a backslash like *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\boost\"*, still didn't work.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600389/cannot-open-include-file-boost-any-hpp-invalid-argument-in-vs-2010) post and explicitly specified it's directory, but even didn't work.

Again, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612060/i-completely-cannot-include-boost-headers) post and did exactly same what is in given answer (as I already built project several times) , but still no success.

However, if I include a library like:

```
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\boost\variant.hpp"
```

Now compiler recognizes it, but now I can see more than 100 errors in Error List window, those errors are pointed to header files of boost libraries, not in my project file which has `variant.hpp` included.

All those errors are `E1696 - cannot open source file "boost\<libraryname.hpp>"` or `E1696 - cannot open source file "boost\<subdirs>\<some other files included in libraryname.hpp>"`

So, if I remove the line `#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\boost\variant.hpp"` from my project's header file, all errors disappear suddenly and project compiles fine! no any single error now!

I want boost to work anyway, so I can use it in projects, but I can't manually edit all those header files and change `<boost\...` to original locations.

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: You should not put boost inside your Visual Studio Install. Next you need to add the folder containing boost to your include folders.

Comment: @drescherjm I did this after trying on a external drive (E:\) and after failure!

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\boost" was the wrong folder to add to your include path. It should have been  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost\"

Comment: ***I did this after trying on a external drive (E:) and after failure!*** You probably made the same path mistake.

Comment: @drescherjm I did what you said with no success!

Comment: I tried adding as you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't use VC++ Directories. Try with `c++>General>Additional Include Directories` And use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\boost` as drescherjm says. Also, you need semicolons between all your includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- make sure you download and install the correct boost version. Installing it in the visual studio directories is possible, but not advised. I suggest you use one of the packages from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/). Assuming you use visual studio 2017 **and** you are developing for 64bit, [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/boost_1_64_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe/download) could perhaps be the correct package for you.
- make sure you do both: adding the include search path and the library search path to your visual studio.

The include search path should point to the boost-installation root directory (the one that contains the `Jamroot` file and a `boost` subdirectory). The library search path should point to the correct library subfolder within the boost installation. This is one of the subfolders that start with `lib64-msvc-**.*` (or `lib32-msvc-*` if you're developing for 32bit).

The default install path of the binary boost package above will install it into `C:\local\boost_<boost version>`. Make sure you use the paths from this installation directory and follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612060/i-completely-cannot-include-boost-headers).

Example:

> Include search path: `C:\local\boost_1_64_0`
>
> Library search path: `C:\local\boost_1_64_0\lib64-msvc-14.1`

Comment: Wow! Your installation package link worked fine! Thanks very much! ;-)