# C++ Return data from a Variant according to the given typename

Tags: c++, variant, typename

I have following function template to return specific type of data from a `VARIANT`, according to the given `typename`.

```
template <typename T>
T VariantGetValue(VARIANT Variant) {

    std::string S(typeid(T).name());

    if (S == "wchar_t* __ptr64") { return Variant.bstrVal; }
    if (S == "unsigned int") { return Variant.uintVal; }
}
```

So, as I needed to return an `unsigned int` type from a `VARIANT`, I tried using above function like:

```
return VariantGetValue<unsigned int>(CV);
```

But, unfortunately compiler seems to ignore `if (S == "....)` case here and gives me error:

> C2440 - 'return': cannot convert from 'BSTR' to 'unsigned int'

But, if I remove the line `if (S == "wchar_t* __ptr64") { return Variant.bstrVal; }`, compiler only gives me following warning:

> C4715 - 'VariantGetValue': not all control paths return a value

Can I suppress this error and continue? Is it safe or are there any alternate ways to do this without compiler errors?

Comment: What is this `VARIANT` type?

Comment: @Justin `VARIANT` type is a structure, which can hold multiple data types.

Comment: It is some sort of MS [WinAPI structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx). Standard C++ doesn't recognize VARIANT nor BSTR objects. Those are MS typedefs.

Comment: So, seems there isn't a solution for this type of thing?

Comment: How bout using `std::variant` and don't ignore warnings?

Comment: @PasserBy I again forgot `std::variant`, I also found it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and will try it now, unfortunately I still cannot use `boost::variant` because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45093370/6536104) issue, which still cannot be fixed.

Comment: Template types must be resolved at compile-time,  this design can never work. You could use template specialization instead

Comment: @M.M That's the point I lost :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have multiple return types based on a branch the code is going to take at runtime.  Your best bet here is to work with explicit specializations.

```
template < typename T >
T VariantGetValue(VARIANT) = delete;

template <>
unsigned int VariantGetValue<unsigned int>(VARIANT Variant)
{
    VARIANT var;
    InitVariantFromUInt32(unsigned int{}, &var);

    if (Variant.vt != var.vt)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad get");
    return Variant.uintVal;
}

template <>
BSTR VariantGetValue<BSTR>(VARIANT Variant)
{
    if (/* check that Variant stores wchar_t* __ptr64 */)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad get");
    return Variant.bstrVal;
}
```

---

This, by the way, is what `std::get` does for `std::variant`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using Variant = std::variant<int,std::string>;

int main()
{
    Variant v(13);

    std::cout << std::get<int>(v) << '\n'; // 13
  //std::cout << std::get<std::string>(v) << '\n'; // std::bad_variant_access
}
```

---

I have implemented a full example to perhaps clarify some questions raised in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Implement a mock VARIANT, don't take this code too seriously

typedef unsigned int VARTYPE;
typedef char* BSTR;
enum { VT_UI4, VT_BSTR };

struct VARIANT
{
    VARIANT() : bstrVal(nullptr) {}
    VARTYPE vt;
    union {
        unsigned int uintVal;
        BSTR bstrVal;
    };
};

void InitVariantFromUInt32(unsigned int u, VARIANT * v)
{
    v->vt = VT_UI4;
    v->uintVal = u;
}

void InitVariantFromString(char const * s, VARIANT * v)
{
    v->vt = VT_BSTR;
    delete[] v->bstrVal;
    v->bstrVal = new char[strlen(s)];
    strcpy(v->bstrVal, s);
}

// VARIANT get value functions

template < typename T >
T VariantGetValue(VARIANT) = delete;

template <>
unsigned int VariantGetValue<unsigned int>(VARIANT Variant)
{
    if (Variant.vt != VT_UI4)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad get");
    return Variant.uintVal;
}

template <>
BSTR VariantGetValue<BSTR>(VARIANT Variant)
{
    if (Variant.vt != VT_BSTR)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad get");
    return Variant.bstrVal;
}

int main()
{
    VARIANT v;
    InitVariantFromUInt32(14, &v);

    std::cout << VariantGetValue<unsigned int>(v) << '\n';
    try {
        std::cout << VariantGetValue<BSTR>(v) << '\n';
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Get failed!" << '\n';
    }

    VARIANT w;
    InitVariantFromString("Hello World!", &w);

    std::cout << VariantGetValue<BSTR>(w) << '\n';

  //std::cout << VariantGetValue<bool>(w) << '\n'; // error: call to deleted function 'VariantGetValue'
}
```

Comment: You can `delete` the default declaration if you want a compiler error. Also, what ist that type `T` in the specializations? Why you throw an exception is also unknown to me. Your functions have a stray semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I also noticed them and fixed with difficulties.

Comment: Why did you changed the answer? Changed answer caused errors.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks for your input.  I corrected my code.  The exception is necessary because the `VARIANT` is just a tagged union, so getting the value will always succeed but will be garbage if the stored and retrieved type do not match.  I made the mistake to copy most of the code from the question.

Comment: @GTAVLover No, the original answer actually would have never compiled.  In the updated answer you have to fill in the type checks yourself (I have no idea how from C++ types to `VARTYPE`), then it will compile.

Comment: @HenriMenke what did you mean by `(/* check that Variant stores...` in your answer?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! I will try it myself.

Comment: @Henri Makes sense, the condition tripped me up. Also, with delete I didn't mean remove completely :) The primary template still has to exist: `template<typename T> T VariantGetValue(VARIANT value) = delete;`

Comment: @GTAVLover I've put some code for the `unsigned int` case but I have no idea whether that works.  I just found that function at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762340(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for that, but now I keep getting IntelliSense error: `function "VariantGetValue<T>(VARIANT) [with T = unsigned int]" (declared at line X) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function.`? How can I use this functon. Unlike I used? Is usage different? I tried using same as I did before.

Comment: @GTAVLover I can't say what you are doing wrong.  A similar code works just fine: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eX2RJxxLbLZ2o3hG

Comment: I used your second answer. When I use function like `return VariantGetValue<unsigned int>(CV);`, I got above error. Why you used a `delete` keyword with the template in your answer? What does it do?

Comment: @Rakete1111 What is the purpose of `delete` keyword here?

Comment: @GTAVLover I've added a full example to the answer.  If you have further questions, perhaps try reading the manual.