# Boost C++ Libaries in Visual Studio 2017 C++ Project - "Cannot open include file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I'm trying to add the Boost C++ Libraries to my C++ project created with Visual Studio 2017.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library). 
When that didn't work I tried the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206577/1504964). Neither solutions worked for me.

What I have done:

- Downloaded `boost_1_69_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe` [from this precompiled boost libraries page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)
- Installed to `D:\local\boost_1_69_0`
- In my project I added `D:\local\boost_1_69_0` to *Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories* and added `D:\local\boost_1_69_0\lib64-msvc-14.1` to *Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories*
- I have my project set to *x64* and the above settings were set in the *x64* configuration

When I try to build my project I get this error:

> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'boost/regex.hpp': No such file or directory

Which points to this line of code in one of my .cpp files:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

Comment: Is there a boost folder inside this folder `D:\local\boost_1_69_0`

Comment: @drescherjm Yes there is.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to *D:\local\boost_1_69_0* folder and see if you have a sub-folder named *include* in there. If you do, then instead of *D:\local\boost_1_69_0* you need to set *D:\local\boost_1_69_0\include* in **Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories**

In other words, try to find the file you are including on your hard drive. Look at the full path to the file. Compare that full path with the path you added to the list of include directories (**Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories**) concatenated with the relative path you provided just before the filename in your include directive (**boost**). See if the two are the same.

If that does not help, then make sure you changed list of include directories for the same build configuration as you are attempting to build (if you build Debug, make sure you changed configuration for Debug too). Since VS 2015 IDE stopped making sure the two are selected in sync, which is annoying.

Comment: There is no *include* folder in there, but I do see `regex.hpp` at `D:\local\boost_1_69_0\boost\regex.hpp` so I tried changing the *Include Directories* path to `D:\local\boost_1_69_0\boost` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: As per your edit, I made sure I am looking at the same config as I'm trying to build.

Comment: Actually, what if you provide D:\local\boost_1_69_0 NOT in "Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories" but in "Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories".

Comment: Although I honestly do not know why would it change anything. The other idea is if you right click on the include file name and select something like "Open Document <boost/regex.hpp>" from the context menu, would it open it?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are copied, then you have to compile the regular library.... If the same version of the compiler copies the machine.

Comment: Can you clarify? I got the precompiled binaries so that I wouldn't have to compile anything I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was failing because I had included the same .cpp file which has the boost include into my unit test project which did NOT have the Include/Library folders set. The settings in my original question work now.